# how to change uuid to jpg format on contact form 7 wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I want to ask. when uploading a jpg file in the form, why is the result in the db converted to some kind of uuid? as long as you want it to be a jpg. has anyone experienced it? I use the contact form 7 plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDONY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdcfa.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.